# Set same value to multiple variables in MySQL with Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm looking for a way to set multiple variables to the same value, elegantly. As there several (around a 100) variables I would like to "reset" to a default value.

The alternative to this would be setting the several 100 variables by updating them one by one, like so:

```
cursor.execute("""UPDATE settings SET value='0' WHERE name='option1'""")
```

but as I mentioned before, there must be a better/more elegant way of doing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean, `variables`? table fields? or actual mysql variables, like `select @foo := 'bar'`?

Comment: Updated the question!

Comment: `update settings set value=0 where name in ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')`. and if you want to set ALL of those settings to zero, then just eliminate the `where` clause entirely.